# Ubuntu 11.04 hangs at "checking battery state" while booting

Tags: boot, ubuntu-11.04

When I try to boot Ubuntu 11.04, it just hangs when it gets to checking battery state. I know this issue is usually related to graphic drivers, but it worked like a charm for months now. Last time I was on Ubuntu I updated my system with the update manager, so maybe an update caused it.

Anyway, I really need Ubuntu. I'm in the middle of work on a website and I have a deadline, so I need some help over here.

Thanks.

p.s.

I tried reinstalling gnome-power-manager. Didn't work. And I'm not on a laptop.

Answer (score 1):

gdm breaks with a recent update

```
mv /etc/gdm/custom.conf /etc/gdm/custom.Conf_bak
```

Comment: This answer is pretty confusing. Can you edit it to explain how that command would solve the problem and how this is related to the question?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge <all drivers of your videocard>
sudo apt-get remove --purge libgl1-mesa-dri
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Finally either:

```
startx
```

or just reboot the machine.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed my system with the same problem (June 30, 2011).  When the computer hangs at 'Checking Battery State'

- use crtl+alt+F1 to open a command shell
- login
- enter the 'startx' command and hit Enter
- gnome loads
- fixed display drivers (purged proprietary and loaded ubuntu drivers)

  (you will have to search the internet to find instructions for your adapter)
   (My card is ATI)

Hope it works for you.